# Hibernate One To Many Inserting - Set<Children> is inserted with wrong order

Tags: hibernate, insert, one-to-many

For example, I have two entities with one to many relation. I just write down the simple code.

```
Class Category {

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
   @Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<Product> products;

}

Class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BookingCode", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Category category;

}
```

Then I want to insert a category with it's products. For example:

```
Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>():
Category category = new Category();

Product fProduct = new Product("1", category);
Product sProduct = new Product("2", category);
Product tProduct = new Product("3", category);
Product fProduct = new Product("4", category);

products.add(fProduct);
products.add(sProduct);
products.add(tProduct);
products.add(fProduct);

category.setProducts(products);

session.persist(category);
```

The above code works normally but the list of products is inserted randomly not same the order I added to the set.

The output products will be "3", "4", "2", "1".

Can anyone explain to me why? And How can I fix this problem?

Comment: A Set normally has no ordering, so this is expected. Why do you need it to be inserted in a specific order?

Comment: Thanks. I found out the reason. I just changed HashSet to LinkedHashSet. That is just because of our requirements.